# Решение задач с модификацией кода

Tags: python

> Определите, при каком наименьшем введённом значении переменной s программа выведет число больше 600.

```
s = int(input())
n = 1
while n < 21:
      s = s - 1
      n = n + 2
print(s)
```

```
for s in range(100000, 100000):
      s1 = s
      n = 1
      while n < 21:
          s = s - 1
          n = n + 2
      if n > 600:
          print(s1)
```

Как найти промежуток, при котором программа хоть что-нибудь выведет?

Comment: for s in range(100000,100000) - ни разу ничего не выведет ))

Comment: при s=611 выведет 601

Comment: ой, ступил)), извиняюсь, там изначально было (-100000,100000), но видимо что-то пошло не так, спасибо за ответ!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

изменив ваш код на:

```
for s in range(1000):
    s1 = s
    n = 1
    while n < 21:
         s1 = s1 - 1
         n = n + 2
    if s1 > 600:
        break
print(s)
```

можно узнать ответ:

```
611
```